# Google sheets script to move row to bottom if marked "done" AND work on all tabs except 1st

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet for projects. First tab is an overview of all the following tabs. I then have one separate tab for each project, and each project tab has a to-do list of tasks.

The set-up for all project tabs are the same - the top 2 rows are headers, 20 rows total (including headers), 3 columns:
A - task
B - status (blank=not started/in progress/done)
C - notes

What I want to do is add a script that will move a row to the bottom of it's own tab once the status is marked as "done". And I want it to run on all tabs except the 1st which is the overview.
Some of the 20 rows will be empty since most of the projects don't have that many tasks. It would be best if "done" tasks are moved to the very last row (row 20) in the tab (leaving empty rows in between pending and done tasks), but not necessary - if they move to the bottom of the active tasks instead, say row 8 if I have 7 tasks filled in (leaving the empty rows on the bottom of the tab) that would also work okay.

(The reason I want this in a script is that on the overview tab I want to pull from each project tab the next task due on the to-do list - which should then always be in A3 - just to make it easier to pick what to do next instead of having to go into each tab to find the next task. This part I know how to do.)

I've tried searching on here and google for answers, but since I don't know how to write scripts myself I haven't been able to figure out what to modify when the poster's question isn't exactly the same as mine.

I found a script that moves the rows marked as "done" to the bottom, but it only works for one tab:

```
function onEdit(e) {
const row = e.range.getRow();
const col = e.range.getColumn();
const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
const lc = as.getLastColumn();
if(as.getName() == "Tab2" && col == 2  && row > 1 && as.getRange(row,col).getValue() == 'done') {
const row_new = as.getRange(row, 1, 1, lc);
row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, lc));
as.deleteRow(row);
} 
}
```

I found another script that works on all tabs, but which also runs on *all* edits to column B.

```
function onEdit(e) {
const sh = e.range.getSheet();
const shts = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];
const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName())
if(~idx && e.range.columnStart == 2  && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {  
const row_new = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,e.range.columnStart);
row_new.copyTo(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,e.range.columnStart));
sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
}
```

Can I merge/modify these two scripts to do work on all tabs but only when the status in column B is marked as "done"? How?

Comment: So this can definitely be done, but if the only reason you want to do all of this is because you want to always point to cell `A3` across project tabs in your overview tab, I would instead recommend just a formula over a script (also because a script inherently brings with it maintenance costs whenever you modify the spreadsheet). You could easily do something like `=index(filter(Project1A:A,Project1B:B<>"Done"),1,1)` which should always give you the next task in that sheet (as long as they are written in order in each sheet)

Comment: Ah, thanks I tried it and that works for me! That's great actually, didn't know that was an option.

Comment: Awesome feel free to reply to your own question with what you came up with to help anyone else that is in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by the suggestion from Miguel Rivera Rios to use a formula instead of a script which worked perfectly for what I needed and was much simpler way to do it.

I added the formula below in column B (next task) of my overview sheet (first tab in the sheet), and just edited the tab names for each row (Project1, Project2, etc). So my overview sheet has column A - projects, B - next tasks (the formula is here which now pulls the next non-completed task from each project tab's to-do list). I also edited the starting row to A3/B3 since my first two rows in the project tabs are headers.

```
=index(filter(Project1!A3:A,Project1!B3:B<>"Done"),1,1)
```